# RequestError: Invalid column name node js sql server passport

Tags: node.js, sql-server, passport.js

Good day, I'm doing a login system using the SQL server (MSSQL), the js node and the passport, the user registry works fine, but the login fails authentication, always returns a user not found, I am a newbie in this and I would like to be guided a little I enclose my code where I do the authentication my code is: file passport.js

```
     passport.use('local.signin', new LocalStrategy({
     usernameField: 'username',
     passwordField: 'passwords',
     passReqToCallback: true
     }, async (req, username, passwords, done) => {
     const request=pool.request();
     //request.input('username',username);
    //request.input('passwords',passwords);
    const rows = await request.query(`SELECT * FROM signUp WHERE username=${username}`);
     console.log(passwords)
    if (rows.length > 0) {
    const user = rows[0];
    const validPassword = await   helpers.matchPassword(passwords,user.passwords)
    if (validPassword) {
      done(null, user, req.flash('success', 'Bienvenido' + user.username));
    } else {
      done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'Incorrect Password'));
    }
  } else {
    return done(null, false, req.flash('message', 'El Nombre de usuario no existe'));
}    
}));

   passport.use('local.signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'passwords',
    passReqToCallback: true
    }, async (req, username, passwords, done) => {

    var user = {
    username : req.body.username,
    passwords :req.body.passwords
   };
   user.passwords = await helpers.encryptPassword(passwords);
   // Saving in the Database
   request.input('username',user.username);
  request.input('passwords',user.passwords);
  const result = await request.query("insert signUp values(@username,@passwords)");
   user.id = result.insertId;
   return done(null, user);
   }));

   passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
   done(null, user.id);
   });

  passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done)=> {
  const rows = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM signUp WHERE id =${id}`);
  done(null, rows[0]);
  });
```

routes.js

```
// SIGNUP
router.get('/signup', (req, res) => {
  res.render('auth/signup');
});

router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local.signup', {
  successRedirect: '/profile',
  failureRedirect: '/signup',
  failureFlash: true
}));

// SINGIN
router.get('/signin', (req, res) => {
  res.render('auth/signin');
});

router.post('/signin', (req, res, next) => {
  req.check('username', 'Username is Required').notEmpty();
  req.check('passwords', 'Password is Required').notEmpty();
  const errors = req.validationErrors();
  if (errors.length > 0) {
    req.flash('message', errors[0].msg);
    res.redirect('/signin');
  }
  passport.authenticate('local.signin', {
    successRedirect: '/profile',
    failureRedirect: '/signin',
    failureFlash: true
  })(req, res, next);
});

router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logOut();
  res.redirect('/');
});

router.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  res.render('profile');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: my table is  Create table signUp(id int identity primary key, username nvarchar(50),passwords nvarchar(100))

Comment: you need to pass a parameter into a single quote into your query. I have the same issue in my code.